# ifconfig silently fails

Tags: linux

I have a Fedora 14 box with an init script that attempts to staticly configure a pair of ethernet ports prior to kicking off a daemon process.  The init script works as expected when manually starting the service from the command prompt.  However, when the script is run as part of the boot process, ifconfig returns zero (no error code or message), but fails to assign different ip addresses to each of the ports.

Any thoughts what could be causing this?

Comment: Do you have actual error messages you can give us? Maybe you can use some Fedora network config UI to reset your networking config and get through it..?

Comment: Speaking from a gentoo perspective, I think I have my init script for eth0 set to start after the boot processes

Comment: @Sean I've merged your accounts, you should be able to reply via comments. Rejecting your edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact reason for the problem is still unclear, however, disabling the 'network' script removed the conflict, allowing my script to correctly configure the ports.

Answer (score 1):

The most common problem I have with custom scripts is I need to set the PATH or use full paths when invoking each program.

It sounds like you have acustom script, so posting your script would be helpful.

Some general bash script debugging ideas:  Put `set -e` near the top of your script to force bash to exit on an error, or for more verbose messages, add error checking and write a message to syslog:

```
/sbin/ifconfig ...
if [ "$?"-ne 0]; then logger "$0 - ifconfig failed with code $?"; exit 1; fi
```

Comment: I have already verified the PATH and the script is doing error checking as suggested, but ifconfig is returning zero without actually changing the interface's address.  Also, the script works as expected with 'service ... start' from the command line, this ONLY happens when during system startup.